# Beautifulsoup: how to getting elements between other elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-scraping

html:

```
<h2>...</h2>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<h2>...</h2>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
```

Expected result:

```
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
```

I mean, getting all content between `h2` elements

Answer (score 2):

Every element has a [nextSibling method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#nextSibling), so you can just get the first h2 element, then loop through the next siblings until you hit the second element.

Pseudo Code (assuming firstElem is the h2 element):

```
p_tags = []
next = firstElem.nextSilbing
while next.name != "h2":
  p_tags.append(next)
  next = next.nextSibling
```

Comment: There is a typo and a complete code example would be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `soup.h2.findNextSiblings('p')` where `soup` is your `BeautifulSoup` instance.

Comment: This solution provides all the elements after h2, not between h2 markup.

Comment: Right, that's what the OP asked for - the content *between* the first `<h2>...</h2>` element and the second `<h2></h2>` element.